# Screen Capture to h.264 using Intel Media SDK

Tags: encoding, directshow, h.264, intel

I am working on a Screen Capture to h.264 bitstream solution using the Intel Media SDK.
I read the new 2nd Generation Intel processors have a hardware accelerated encoder so i am expecting the encode latency to drop and make it realtime.

Using ffmpeg 32bit version doing a screen capture and x264 i get an end to end latency of 200ms on the Pi. Well the Raspberry pi has a hardware decoder so i am guessing it does the decode in around 80ms. I used a Intel i5 520M and a 1st gen i7 to do the decoding the end to end was 250-350ms latency after using the Raspberry pi that went down to 150-200.

How do i link the Direct Show Screen Capture filter to the Intel Media SDK input? 
there is not documentation i can follow, if anyone can shine some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the success of h.264 screen encoding by Direct3X + H.264 H/W encoder using Intel Media SDK.

- screen shot by DirectX : 55ms
- RGB4 -> NV12 converting by Intel Media SDK / VPP : 1ms
- H.264 encoding by Intel Media SDK / H/W encoder : 7ms

Refer this link:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/358602